Break newline in react native with react i18next
I am using react-i18next i18next in a react-native project. I am having trouble adding a new line in the translated text.
// locales_en.json
"FOO": "I am text \n that should have a new line

That \n is not doing anything. How would I add a line break in the translation files?

{
  "FOO": "I am text\nthat should have a new line\nThat\nis not doing anything."
}

In your React Native code, ensure you're rendering the translated text using a component that supports newline characters, such as the Text component:
import React from 'react';
import { Text } from 'react-native';
import { useTranslation } from 'react-i18next';

const MyComponent = () => {
  const { t } = useTranslation();

  return <Text>{t('FOO')}</Text>;
};

export default MyComponent;


Do you also know how to make text bold?


you can choose from here:
('normal', 'bold', '100', '200', '300', '400', '500', '600', '700', '800', '900')

I mean in the translation file. If I want one word in this string bold There is one <b>word</b> that should be bold

Oh I see. You just need to add dangerouslySetInnerHTML inside 
{
"FOO": "There is one word that should be bold"
}
<Text
  dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: t('FOO') }}
/>


Hm, not sure if that works... Its not HTML what I am writing nor what react-native compiles to...
